# Why was my comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, closed-questions

I added a comment to [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106167/what-are-the-indications-of-an-investigation-in-crime-network-cosa-nostra) question explaining what I thought it needed in order to get the question reopened. As far as I am concerned, my comment was no different to the countless comments I and other people write to help get questions into shape. It certainly wasn't an answer, and was constructive.

I would be extremely grateful if the moderator responsible for deleting the comment could explain their reasoning, as I'm sure I must be missing something but have no idea what it might be.

Comment: I can't read your deleted comment, but it seems it's obsolete since the question didn't get closed ([doppelgreener edited the question instead to leave it open](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/close/39328))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I removed the comment. It said the following:

> At a minimum we need some indication of how this relates to a role-playing game you are running or planning for. A system and genre would also be helpful, as an answer for a medieval setting would be completely different for something science fiction based.

They specified a system already. It's a game called Crime Network Cosa Nostra. I thought it specified no system at first as well, but it turns out it did. Since it's clear enough about genre, system, etc, I removed the comment as no longer needed.

Originally it just had [crime-network](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crime-network) for a tag which doesn't look like a system, but the tag got renamed at some point around when both you and I were looking at the question, so now it's clearer.

---

Actually it looks like I might have not understood clearly, and I've made an assumption about what they were saying based on some edits. I'm closing the question temporarily so we can seek clarity and confirmation. I apologise for that mixup. Let's see what we can do getting the question clear with the author.